# List of Best CTAN packages

Tags: best-practices, ctan

Some of the packages of CTAN are really good but not discovered by many. I recently encountered one of the good ones, namely latexindent, and I thought that would be great if everyone introduces the best he/she is aware of. So,

Kindly please introduce what you found useful in CTAN that should be recommended to others.

Comment: Of course the best is [`ducksay`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ducksay)!